# Setting DB2 Client Audit information with a dbcp connection pool in a Java app

Tags: jdbc, db2, connection-pooling, audit, apache-commons-dbcp

I'm developing Java apps on Tomcat 5.5 using JNDI to connect to shared dbcp connection pools with JDBC 3.0 drivers and DB2 8 on zOS and also DB2 9 on LUW.  In my app, I use org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean to get the dataSource and feed it into an org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate to run the queries.  This has been a fairly good solution so far, but our DBAs are requesting that we provide better granularity for auditing SQL performance.  Currently, all portlets and apps use the same connection pool to connect to the database and the only way to distinguish between apps is to match the SQL run with the SQL in each app.  We don't want to create seperate pools for each app.   DB2 provides several methods on their DB2Connection from the driver that allow us to set audit information.

setDB2ClientApplicationInformation
    setDB2ClientUser
    setDB2ClientWorkstation
    setDB2ClientAccountingInformation

My question is... what's the best way to set these values on a connection from a connection pool.  Do I need to access the underlying connection in order to set these values?  Should I clear them before returning the connection to the pool?  Does anyone have code examples?